# REST API in MEAN stack, passed id vs id from session

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, rest, session

I'm building a web app using MEAN stack.

While building the REST API I see a lot of examples with the following endpoint

```
/api/contacts/:id
```

for GET, PUT and DELETE methods.

I did something different, I enabled session in the Express framework and now I can see the user document id (for mongoDB) under req.session.req.payload._id when I do a HTTP request which enables me to access the document.

That why I also don't need to expose the user document id in the URL when I do 
a HTTP request.

My question is which method is better and safer to use?

Also, how can I get the user id in Angular to pass to the HTTP request in case I don't use sessions.

And a final one... I also use JWT as middle-ware before calling the function which updates the DB. This gives me some sense of security but wouldn't it be possible for a user with the correct token to do HTTP requests with different ids and by that getting, updating and deleting other users data?
This won't be possible with the current method I'm using (sessions)

Answer (score 0):

When you need to pass the user ID to the endpoints then your client code will need to know that and it's the backend that needs to provide it somehow - either as part of the returned toked or usually as part of the response to a successful login request. The client can store it in a cookie or a local storage to use later.

It is not very practical, though, to have to provide the ID of the user in every route like:

```
/api/contacts/:id
```

When your users need to be able to access other users contacts then you may need to use the ID in the route and you may not want to have another set of routes for a situation when the user wants to manipulate his or her own contacts.

What I've seen sometimes done in practice in situations like this is to use a special value for the ID like "me" and have your backend translate all routes like this:

```
/api/contacts/me
```

to:

```
/api/contacts/:id
```

where `:id` is the ID of the user who made the request, taken from the session. This can be done with a middleware to substitute the value for all routes at once, and then your normal controllers could use it like it was provided in the route to begin with.

Comment: Hey, why do I need the "me" if I'm getting the id already from the session? I think I can just leave it as /api/contacts and each user will get the requested data according to the session. Also I don't need for users to access other users data. It's just doesn't look safe to me to allow a users to do HTTP requests with any id they would like.